# Why my ubuntu 20.04 is not working as fast as expected?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, ssd

i am new to Linux . I have downloaded ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop(i5 7200 , 4gb Ram )on a separate ssd disk (120gb) from the one I have installed windows 10.
The problem here is , that ubuntu is very slow , apps take more than normal to open and even my typing has a delay . A friend of mine who has the same specs at his laptop never faced a problem , so i imagine its not the hardware . The only thing i managed to find by myself was that although all the cpus are operating between 5%-20% the cpu2 is operating above 90% but i don't really know the reason why.

Any help would be valuable.

Comment: Open system monitor, and find which process is consuming all that CPU cycles.

Comment: I cant find any process that causes this problem. Only firefox uses a 15% of cpu , and a process named Xorg( i dont know what it is ) uses around 5%-10% . So , its something else i guess

Comment: You should also check how much RAM you are using, if your swap is being used, and how full your SSD is. SSDs tend to become slow when filled >90%.